# ¿Como poner una pantalla de espera en WPF y C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Quiero poner una pantalla de espera y me parece que tengo utilizar hilos sin tener poner un tiempo defino como

```
"System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);"
```

Quiero ponerlo en lo que carga realmente la aplicacion o hace un proceso pero no se como.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de lo que quieras hacer. La manera más sencilla de hacerlo es usando una imagen como ***Splash screen***, básicamente es seleccionar una imagen, desde el explorador de soluciones darle **clic derecho > Propiedades > Acción de compilación** = "SplashScreen". Hecho esto, solo basta con ejecutar la aplicación y verás esa imagen antes de la ventana principal. [Aquí la guía de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-wpf-application).

Si quieres ponerle más *caché* a tu pantalla de carga, puedes guiarte con [esta pregunta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22026639/5360283). Básicamente necesitas crear una ventana `Splash.xaml` y *apuntarla* como la ventana principal de tu aplicación desde el archivo `App.xaml`:

#### Splash.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TuApp.Splash"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Splash" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Height="21" Margin="91,61,108,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">Splash Screen</TextBlock>
        <ProgressBar Name="progBar" Margin="22,122,16,109" Minimum="0" Maximum="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

y dándole `F7` al mismo `Splash.xaml` debe salir el *code behind* (`Splash.xaml.cs`). Lo modificas así:

```
public partial class Splash : Window
{
    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Splash_Loaded);
    }

    void Splash_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IAsyncResult result = null;
        // Delegado que se ejecutará cuando la carga se haya completado.
        AsyncCallback initCompleted = delegate(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            App.Current.ApplicationInitialize.EndInvoke(result);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Invoker)delegate { Close(); });
        };

        // Llama al proceso de inicialización de la aplicación.
        result = App.Current.ApplicationInitialize.BeginInvoke(this, initCompleted, null);
    }

    // Actualiza la barra de progreso de la pantalla de carga
    public void SetProgress(double progress)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Invoker)delegate { progBar.Value = progress; });           
    }
}
```

#### App.xaml y App.xaml.cs

```
<Application x:Class="TuApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="Splash.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

namespace TuApp
{
    internal delegate void Invoker();
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        internal delegate void ApplicationInitializeDelegate(Splash splashWindow);
        internal ApplicationInitializeDelegate ApplicationInitialize;

        public App()
        {
            ApplicationInitialize = MyAppInit;
        }

        public static new App Current
        {
            get { return Application.Current as App; }
        }

        private void MyAppInit(Splash splashWindow)
        {
            // Aquí puedes hacer las cosas que necesites e ir actualizando una barra de progreso
            // En este ejemplo, simplemente esperar medio segundo
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            splashWindow.SetProgress(0.2);
            ...
            splashWindow.SetProgress(1);

            // Al finalizar tus procesos, inicias la ventana principal
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Invoker)delegate
            {
                MainWindow = new VentanaPrincipal();
                MainWindow.Show();
            });           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando quieres poner una pantalla de espera al inicio de la aplicación es normalmente porque tienes un proceso síncrono que se tira un tiempo y evita la carga del resto de controles.

Bien para que te siga cargando los controles debes hacer ese proceso **asíncrono**. Es un tema algo complejo pero espero poder darte las pautas necesarias para que te inicies y puedas seguir luego el camino por tu cuenta.

Vamos a suponer que tu proceso que tarda bastante se llama `ArranqueAplicacion`

```
public static void ArranqueAplicacion()
{
    // Hace lo que tenga que hacer, yo lo simulo con un Thread.Sleep
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Lo puedes hacer asíncrono de esta forma tan sencilla, pero te recomiendo que leas [un poco de información](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) y busques por internet:

```
public async Task ArranqueAplicacionAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => ArranqueAplicacion());
}
```

Bien ahora supongamos que estás arrancando la aplicación desde el formulario `MainWindow` y en el evento `Window_Loaded` de la misma está el proceso que tarda tanto, ahora llamarás de forma asíncrona al método `ArranqueAplicacionAsync`, por lo que antes puedes mostrar un panel que ocupe la pantalla mostrando el aviso de "inicializando la aplicación" o algo así, yo voy a usar algo más sencillo un `Label` llamado `lblEjemplo`, para que después de la llamada asíncrona indique que el proceso de carga ha finalizado.

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.lblEjemplo.Content = "Iniciando la aplicación...";

    await ProcesoPesado.ArranqueAplicacionAsync();

    this.lblEjemplo.Content = "Carga finalizada";
}
```

Si lo ejecutas verás como esta vez se muestra el formulario completo con el valor inicial del `Label` como "Iniciando la aplicación..." y pasados esos 5 segundos que he puesto termina cambiando a "Carga finalizada".

Al dejar el gestor del evento `Window_Loaded` como asíncrono permites a la ventana que cambie los valores de los controles y se muestren a la vez en el formulario.

Tan sólo te he dado un punto de partida, esto luego lo puedes complicar todo lo que quieras.

Puedes ver el código y descargártelo desde mi [GitHub](https://github.com/RublenX/StackOverflow/tree/master/RublenX.RespuestasRapidas/WpfAppFrk).

Espero que te sirva.